# mysqldb doesn't write on db

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm trying to execute a query in a Magento database, the problem is that the Python API doesn't write to my database. It seems that the query is never executed.

I suppose that the queries are correctly generated, they work in mysql cli. Maybe I don't use the API correctly, here is the code:

http://pastebin.com/5pUJc7ve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot the commit.

Add

```
connessione.commit()
connessione.close()
```